# How do I add commands to the boot sequence?

Tags: debian, boot

I have recently been trying to iron out a few minor problems with my new Debian 8.6 ppc install. I have found or been given commands to run in the terminal which fix them. I have added these commands to `/etc/init.d/rc.local` and to `/etc/rc.local` as well as `.profile` but I still need to run them in the terminal after booting and logging in to get them to work.

One is `sudo modprobe snd-aoa-i2sbus` to get the sound working and the other is `synclient TapButton1=1` to enable touchpad tap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run commands to those tasks. Use the specific configuration files to deal with module loding and peripheral configuration.

## Sound module loading

The `snd-aoa-i2sbus` you could solve by editing your `/etc/modules` adding a line with the name of the module. It will be something like:

```
root@host:~# cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
snd-aoa-i2sbus
loop
```

**Module options while loading**: If you need to change specific module parameters during loading, add these parameters to `/etc/modprobe.d/<your_module>.conf`. Check what are the possible(if any) parameters by executing `modinfo snd-aoa-i2sbus | grep '^parm:'`

## Touchpad configuration

To change touchpad buttons, edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`(create if does not exists) and put the following content inside.

```
Section "InputClass"
          Identifier "touchpad catchall"
          Driver "synaptics"
          MatchIsTouchpad "on"
          Option "TapButton1" "1"
          Option "TapButton2" "2"
          Option "TapButton3" "3"
EndSection
```

Just map button behavior/action using the `Option` parameter, changing the touchpad buttons to better fit your needs. As pointed out by comments to this answer, if `xorg.conf.d/` directory is missing, is just a matter of creating it inside `/etc/X11`. There is no need to tweak `xorg.conf` directly.

Comment: X11 does not contain xorg.conf.d, it contains: fonts, xinit, Xresources,     xsm,    openbox,  xkb, Xsession, Xwrapper.config, app-defaults, rgb.txt,  Xreset, Xsession.d, default-display-manager, X, Xreset.d, and Xsession.options. Is this because its a power pc?

Comment: The Sound module loading section solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe it is because Debian does not uses the `xorg.conf.d` directory to manage separated file configs. Take a look at your `xorg.conf` and search for the `InputClass` section, if there is one.

Comment: I just had to make the directory, now it works fine so both issues solved by @nwildner!

Comment: Glad it worked and you figured out that creating this dir made the solution work :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Jessie before, but I have blacklisted modules by placing program.conf within /etc/modules-load.d/

For example:

```
/etc/modules-load.d/virtio-net.conf
# Load virtio-net.ko at boot
virtio-net
```

Here is a reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules

If modules-load.d directory does not exist, then /lib/modules/ directory may be of interest.

Comment: You can still link to the other question, but you should make a complete answer out of it because, as it is currently, it will get flagged as a link-only answer.

Comment: Fair enough...changed